# Number of idempotent ultrafilters.

Tags: abstract-algebra, set-theory

How many idempotent ultrafilters (under addition) are there, in terms of cardinality?  Also, does the set of idempotents have any nice topological properties?

Comment: See [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/345889/how-much-do-idempotent-ultrafilters-generate-in-terms-of-semigroups?rq=1).

Comment: @Dietrich: Seeing how the linked question was cross-posted to MathOverflow, where the OP has commented asking *this* very question well before posting this question, I imagine he is aware of that question.

Comment: There are $2^{\mathfrak{c}}$ idempotents in $\beta \omega$ - See Theorem 6.9 in Hindman and Strauss, Algebra in the Stone-Cech compactification: Theory and applications, Walter de Gruyter, Berlin/New York, 1998.

Comment: Ashutosh, is this hard to show?

Comment: I don't think so. I wrote the main steps of their proof. They shouldn't be too hard to check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the main steps of the proof from the Hindman-Strauss book.

Step 1: Let $A = \{2^n : n \geq 1\}$. Suppose $p, q \in \beta \mathbb{N} \setminus \mathbb{N}$, $A \in p \cap q$ and $p \neq q$. Then $(\beta \mathbb{N} + p) \cap (\beta \mathbb{N} + q) = \phi$. In particular, $\beta \mathbb{N}$ has $2^{\mathfrak{c}}$ pairwise disjoint left ideals.

Step 2: Every left ideal in $\beta \mathbb{N}$ contains a minimal left ideal.

Step 3: Every minimal left ideal in $\beta \mathbb{N}$ contains an idempotent.

It follows that $\beta \mathbb{N}$ has $2^{\mathfrak{c}}$ idempotents.

Comment: In the terminology of Bergelson-Hindman 1990, do you mean Right ideal?

Comment: The definition of a left ideal here is: $\phi \subsetneq J \subseteq \beta \mathbb{N}$ is a left ideal if $\beta \mathbb{N} + J \subseteq J$.

Comment: Steps 2 and 3 follow from some compactness arguments, if we replace left with right. I have no idea how to do that for left ideals.  I think maybe the definition of the operation is switched.